# Embed XML element in inline VB code

Tags: xml, vb.net

Consider the following code in VB9:

```
Dim text = "Line1<br/>Line2"
Dim markup = <span><%= text %></span>.ToString
```

While I was hoping markup would end up being `<span>Line1<br/>Line2</span>`, it actually evaluates to `<span>Line1&lt;br/&gt;Line2</span>`.

Is there any way to get the value of the variable not to be HTML encoded?

P.S.: This is an oversimplified example of what I'm trying to do. I know this could be rewritten a number of ways to make it work, but the way my code is constructed, un-encoding the variable would be optimal. If that's not possible, then I'll go down a different road.

More detail: The "text" is coming from a database, where a user can enter free-form text, with carriage returns. The output is HTML, so somehow I need to get the value from the database and convert the carriage returns to line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is "By Design."  When embedding a string expression inside an XML literal the value will be escaped to be a legal string value.

To get the behavior you are looking for you'll need to be embedding an XElement/XNode within an XML literal.  Take the following example.  It will correctly keep the `<br/>` tag as an XElement.

```
Dim text2 = <a>Line<br/>Line</a>
Dim markup2 = <span><%= text2 %></span>.ToString
```

One way to achieve this is to fake an XElement.  To make the text a valid string, simply wrap it on both ends with a normal tag, `<a>` for example.  This is now a parsable XML fragment.  Once you have an XElement, it's easy to get the embedded behavior you are looking for

```
Dim text = "Line1<br/>Line2"
Dim text2 = XElement.Parse("<a>" + text + "</a>")
Dim markup = <span><%= text2.Nodes %></span>.ToString
```

Comment: See detail above (just added). I don't have the luxury of separating the text into elements unless I parse the incoming text and build each element, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Check out the additional comment i made.  You will have to parse complete inputs but not each individual one.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, you can directly write **XML literals**

```
Dim markup As XElement = <span>Line1<br/>Line2</span>
```

- The VB compiler **“sees” the XML,**
- and creates the **equivalent XLinq** commands for you.

Read more about [XML Literals in VB.NET](http://donxml.com/allthingstechie/archive/2005/10/10/2239.aspx).

Comment: That is correct, but it doesn't address the problem. I have text (from the db) with carriage returns. I can replace the CR's with "<br/>", but the XML literal doesn't recognize them when I use it in <%# text %>. @JaredPar's XElement.Parse got me around this issue.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah, I didn't notice that you already knew about XML literals!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using XElementRaw.

```
Dim markup = <span><%= text %></span>.ToHTML()
```

Here's the ToHTML() extension:

```
''' <summary>
''' Convert an XElement to a string.  Differences between this and .ToString():<br />
''' 1) Will not throw errors on invalid characters<br />
''' 2) Will not escape characters, such as &amp;<br />
''' 3) Will not include &lt;![CDATA[ ]]&gt; wrappers around text<br />
''' 4) Works with .XElementRaw( ) extension to add a "raw" string (i.e. malformed HTML) directly into the flow
''' </summary>
''' <param name="myElement"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
<Extension()>
Public Function ToHTML(ByVal myElement As XElement, Optional OmitXmlDeclaration As Boolean = True) As String
    'set up XSL transform, set checkCharacters to false
    Static firstTime As Boolean = True
    Static xslt As Xsl.XslCompiledTransform = New Xsl.XslCompiledTransform()
    Static settings As XmlWriterSettings

    'if element is null then it cannot contain any HTML
    If myElement Is Nothing Then Return ""

    If firstTime Then
        SyncLock xslt
            If firstTime Then
                Dim xslDefinition As XElement = <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
                                                    <xsl:output media-type="text/html" method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
                                                    <xsl:template match="/|*|@*|comment()">
                                                        <xsl:copy>
                                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                                                        </xsl:copy>
                                                    </xsl:template>
                                                    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('pcr1Raw')">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                                                    </xsl:template>
                                                    <xsl:template match="text()">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
                                                    </xsl:template>
                                                </xsl:stylesheet>

                xslt.Load(xslDefinition.CreateReader())
                settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone() 'need clone or else most properties are readonly
                settings.CheckCharacters = False
                settings.DoNotEscapeUriAttributes = True
                settings.NewLineOnAttributes = False
                settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None
                settings.Indent = False
                settings.WriteEndDocumentOnClose = False
                settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment

                firstTime = False
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End If

    'now run the actual transform
    Dim sb = New Text.StringBuilder()
    Using w = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)
        xslt.Transform(myElement.CreateReader(), w)
    End Using

    If OmitXmlDeclaration = False Then
        Dim decl As New XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes")
        Return decl.ToString() & vbCrLf & sb.ToString()
    Else
        Return sb.ToString()
    End If
End Function
```